# XCTest Error: The bundle couldn’t be loaded. Try reinstalling the bundle

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, xctest, nsbundle

After I run ProjectNameTests.m (empty test file) by doint `Product -> Test` the project builds successfully, but it throws and gives me the following error:

```
2016-01-10 11:25:32.677 xctest[66104:5611958] The bundle “ProjectNameTests” couldn’t be loaded. Try reinstalling the bundle.
2016-01-10 11:25:32.677 xctest[66104:5611958] (dlopen(/Users/XYZ/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-dnwnjlzdzxbcyydkxsumlvokmhvk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ProjectNameTests.xctest/ProjectNameTests, 265): Symbol not found: _FBSDKErrorArgumentCollectionKey
  Referenced from: /Users/XYZ/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-dnwnjlzdzxbcyydkxsumlvokmhvk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ProjectNameTests.xctest/ProjectNameTests
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Agents/xctest
 in /Users/XYZ/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-dnwnjlzdzxbcyydkxsumlvokmhvk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ProjectNameTests.xctest/ProjectNameTests)
Program ended with exit code: 83
```

I've tried removing UIKit from Tests, changing Match-O type, switching simulator to iPhone 5 and other things suggested in similar answers, without any luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Does any one found any solution for this? I am still facing this issue for UI tests, after setting bundle loader.

Answer (score 4):

Answering this years later (Xcode 13.4) but hopefully this will help someone!

My issue was related to Code Signing.

Go to your test target's **Build Settings** and:

- Change **Code Signing Identity > Debug** to **Apple Development**
- Change **Code Signing Identity > Release** to **Apple Distribution**.

You may have to create an **Apple Distribution** certificate if one does not already exist.

Here are the steps to create it:

- Go to **Xcode > Preferences > Accounts**. Click on the account that you are using for your app.
- Click on **Manage Certificates**
- Click on the `+` icon in the bottom left and select `Apple Distribution`.

Answer (score 2):

I just had a similar issue and it turned out that the Xcode project was set to a deployment target of 7.2, but expecta and septa required 8.0 or greater.

Answer (score 2):

I have an error with exit code 83 not being able to recognize a symbol from an external library added to project.

In my case, it was resolved by setting "Host application" to app in the tests target General configuration. I also have checked "Allow testing host Application APIs"

Comment: I don't have the app showing in the list, it is only showing none, any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

Even I got the same error
where I have solved it following the below step

> Set the **Test Host** in **Build settings** of the test target to
>   **$(BUNDLE_LOADER)**

Actually I was trying to add unit tests to already exists project where I should follow the procedure in the method given in the link [Adding Unit Tests to an existing iOS project with Xcode 4](http://twobitlabs.com/2011/06/adding-ocunit-to-an-existing-ios-project-with-xcode-4/) where I have missed that step

Comment: I was getting the "bundle could not be loaded" error and after trying all other ideas from StackOverflow, this change helped me as follows:

Comment: I was getting the "bundle could not be loaded" error and after trying all other ideas from StackOverflow, this change helped me as follows:  The next time I ran the test, the message was that "Testing should be run in the simulator, not in the device".  After trying in the Simulator, the tests are running fine....

Comment: Adding unit tests to an existing project is a nightmare beyond words

Answer (score 1):

I think I am late, But what worked for me is.

When creating Unit Testing Bundle for existing project check following points.

- Testing Bundle should be on the Same Team, Development Team should be same.
- Organisation Identifiers Should be same.

If you're using Firebase Pods

- Copy All Firebase Pods in Test Target and Install Pods

Restart the Xcode. And you're good to go.

Comment: This saved my bacon today, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, this error can also happen for a dumb reason : zero tests in target.

Double check your configuration.

Answer (score -1):

Removing and re-adding the scheme worked for me.